# Discriminant of q-analogs of positive integers

Tags: reference-request, discriminant, q-analogs

Computations suggest that the discriminant of the polynomial  $[n]_{q^m}=1+q^{m}+\dots+q^{(n-1)m}$  with respect to $q$  is $ \pm {\left( {m{{(mn)}^{n - 2}}} \right)^m}.$
Could you please give me a reference where I can find simple proofs of these results?