# Discriminant of numbers

Tags: number-theory, cyclotomic-polynomials, discriminant, q-analogs

In a previous post on [a $q$-analog of number theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4833031/q-analog-of-number-theory) I present the fact that any $q$-number can be written as a unique product of cyclotomic polynomials, similar to the fundamental theorem of arithmetic. Namely that if $n = p_1^{\nu_{p_1}(n)}p_2^{\nu_{p_2}(n)}...p_i^{\nu_{p_i}(n)}$ then I show that

$${[n]}_q = \prod_i\left(\prod_{j=0}^{\nu_{p_i}(n)-1}\Phi_{p_i}\left(q^{p_i^j\prod_{r \leq i}p_r^{k_r}}\right)\right)$$

---

Some notation quickly:

A $q$-number is denoted as ${[n]}_q$ and defined as
$${[n]}_q = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}q^k$$
We have the following rules for multiplication and addition
$${[nm]}_q = {[n]}_q{[m]}_{q^n}$$
$${[n+m]}_q = {[n]}_q+q^n{[m]}_q$$

---

I was just playing around with this and was curious as to what the 'discriminant of a number' would look like through its extension as a $q$-analog. I tried two different attempts to come to a closed form solution. My first attempt was simply in seeing that $\{q = \zeta_n^k, \,\,\,k<n: {[n]}_q=0\}$ and hence the [discriminant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant) is
$$D{[n]}_{q} = \prod_{k<j}(\zeta_n^k-\zeta_n^j)^2$$
$$ = \prod_{k<j}(e^{\frac{2\pi i k}{mn}}-e^{\frac{2\pi i j}{mn}})^2$$
This was my first attempt. I stopped here mainly because I didn't immediately see where to go from here, and because I wanted to use the '$q$-analog of prime factorization' to find a closed form solution. So here it is,

Given that
$${[n]}_q = \prod_i\left(\prod_{j=0}^{\nu_{p_i}(n)-1}\Phi_{p_i}\left(q^{p_i^j\prod_{r \leq i}p_r^{k_r}}\right)\right)$$

We know that
$$D(\Phi_p(x)) = (-1)^{(p-1)/2} p^{p-2}$$
for prime $p$

We also have that for two monic polynomials $f, g$ with real coefficients
$$D(fg)
= D(f)D(g)\prod_{i,j}(a_i-b_j)^2$$
So, for example
$$D{[6]}_q = D{[2]}_qD{[3]}_q\prod_{i,j}(\zeta_2^i-\zeta_3^j)^2$$
Since ${[2]}_q$ and ${[3]}_q$ are 'prime' and cannot be factored as cyclotomic polynomials other than $\Phi_2(q)$ and $\Phi_3(q)$, we get the simplified expression
$$D{[6]}_q = -6i\prod_{k,j}(\zeta_2^k-\zeta_3^j)^2$$
I couldn't find a way to come to a 'nice' closed form as suggested by [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4173881/discriminant-of-q-analogs-of-positive-integers). All I seem to get is
$$D{[n]}_q = \prod_i(-1)^{(p_i-1)/2} p_i^{p_i-2}\prod_{k,j}...\prod_{l,m}(\zeta_{p_1}^k-\zeta_{p_2}^j)^2...(\zeta_{p_{i-1}}^l-\zeta_{p_i}^m)^2$$
without any way to simplify further. I know I must be missing something obvious. Any help is appreciated!